# Error when submitting Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, sql

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Good day, I have been looking at this for hours and I just can not find the problem any help why i keep getting this error would help.

```html
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
 $data = getPosts();
  if(empty($data[0]) || empty($data[1]) || empty($data[2]) || empty($data[3]))
  {
   echo 'Enter player id number to update';
  } else {
    $updateStmt = $statement = $db->prepare('UPDATE players SET Id_num = :idnum, Name = :name, Surname = :sunrame, Club = :club WHERE Id_num = :idnum');
    $updateStmt->execute(array(
       ':idnum' =>$data[0],
                                                        ':name' =>$data[1],
                                                        ':surname' =>$data[2],
                                                        ':club' =>$data[3]
    ));
    if($updateStmt)
    
    {
    
                                  
     echo 'Player updated successfully';
                                   
                                }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why set Id_num column to the same value as before?

Comment: In the event that the ID changes, lets say a mistake was made when capturing the data initially.

Comment: But you have :idnum both as SET parameter and WHERE parameter. To me it looks like you want to set Id_num to the same value as before. If you want to set to another value, why not have :old_idnum and :new_idnum?

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but your query refers to `:sunrame`, and you pass `:surname` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have five params then you must bind 5 values.

In you case   You must assign idNum two time

```
            $updateStmt->execute(array(
                        ':idnum' =>$data[0],
                         ':name' =>$data[1],
                         ':surname' =>$data[2],
                         ':club' =>$data[3],
                         ':idnum' =>$data[0]
            ));
```

And Just for test try using differnt param ref for idnum

```
    $updateStmt = $statement = $db->prepare('UPDATE players 
                SET Id_num = :idnum
                , Name = :name
                , Surname = :sunrame
                , Club = :club 
                WHERE Id_num = :idnum2');
    $updateStmt->execute(array(
                    ':idnum' =>$data[0],
                     ':name' =>$data[1],
                     ':surname' =>$data[2],
                     ':club' =>$data[3],
                     ':idnum2' =>$data[0]
        ));
```

Comment: I have update the answer with just a suggestion  .. but this suggestion a part check better you code because the error you have should be  solved  by my answer ..

Comment: Same error occurred. I removed empty($data[0]) || after going back step by step and it solved it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. I found the problem.

if(empty($data[0]) || should not have been there it is working perfectly now.

See code below.

```html
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
 $data = getPosts();
  if(empty($data[1]) || empty($data[2]) || empty($data[3]))
  {
   echo 'Enter player id number to update';
  } else {
    $updateStmt = $statement = $db->prepare('UPDATE players SET Name = :name, Surname = :surname, Club = :club WHERE Id_Num = :idnum');
    $updateStmt->execute(array(
                                                       ':idnum' =>$data[0],
                                                        ':name' =>$data[1],
                                                        ':surname' =>$data[2],
                                                        ':club' =>$data[3],
    ));
    if($updateStmt)
    
    {
    
                                  
     echo 'Player updated successfully';
                                   
                                }
   }
}
```